# MagicalRecord 2.3 Temporary Objects

Tags: ios, core-data, save, magicalrecord, updating

sometimes I need to update an already persistend managed object with another temporary managed object created from a server response. The temporary object must be discarded and the other one should be saved immediately after the update operation. In MagicalRecord (MR) 2.3++ it is recommended to save objects like so:

```
- (void)updateObject:(NSManagedObject*)alreadyPersistedObject withDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        NSManagedObject *updatedObject = [NSManagedObject MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
        [MyParserHandler parseDictionary:dictionary intoManagedObject:updatedObject];

        // update some properties of alreadyPersistedObject using updatedObject
    }];
}
```

I know that we should initialize temporary objects using temporary local contexts in earlier versions of MR. Is that also true for MR 2.3 and higher?

If YES, can somebody please give me a code example for that and needs the temp context be a child of the [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] and how to discard this context after usage?

If NO, what is the preferred technique to do this now?

Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Just to restate the problem, you are trying to update existing data from an external data source into your core data store. You create a background context and have temporary objects into which you import this external data, and then save. So what you want to do is have those new changes propagate to your existing in-memory objects.

If this is the case, then if you simply use the body of that method, the default context provided by MagicalRecord will have those updates upon the completion of that block. MagicalRecord is trying to do much of that merging work for you. If you just create your temporary object inside the `saveWithBlock:` method, the save will eventually merge those changes to the default context. So, if your objects are in that context, they will receive those changes as a result of the save.

If you find that you need some more control over your merging of data, I suggest you use the built-in Core Data merging mechanisms rather than trying to merge manually. In this case, you should use the parent/child context relationships, or the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` to merge in changes from another context. The code for those solutions is fairly common on the internet.

Comment: No, the keypoint for what I need to know is: How to create throw-away objects - objects that I need to create but don't want to save to the peristent store.

Comment: Just delete them in the context. They won't be persisted. Or, you can create a "scratch context" where all the objects you create will just go away when the context is dealloced.

Comment: Thanks, but how to create that "scratch context"? in magicalrecord 3.0 I can't find the old "[NSManagedObjectContext MR_newContext]"

Comment: @silvaric think it's now called MR_contextWithParent: